# Display .NET MVC unit test results on a page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

I'm wondering if it's possible to display results from unit tests on a single page?

For example:

- Call controller/action
- Run unit tests
- Return view with result

TIA

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but that question is about getting the current executed view, which is not what I'm looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you can customize your command line tool to return kind of html output, or find a ready xslt for various test result formats.

If it's mstest, you can use mstest.exe and process the resulting trx file.
If it's nunit-console.exe, you can process TestResults.xml

Since you've got html in a temporary file, use [FileResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.fileresult.aspx) to return the file as an action result.